# mockito 3 kotlin. cannot mock final class

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I am trying to mock an object but android studio keeps reporting that a final class cannot be mocked. My setup and attempts are as follows;

for my depenencies I have;

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3'
```

my code is like this;

```
class CategoryFile {
    private lateinit var categories: Categories

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        categories = mock(Categories::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun validData() {
        categories.getName(0)
    }
}
```

When I try to run validData() I get the `final class cannot be mocked` exception.

I have tried using the `mock-maker-inline` option place in this directory;

[image]

I read that this option would be removed once a programatic way was implemented. but haven't been able to find any references to how to do it programatically online anywhere.

I also read in some SO posts that you are also supposed to include it in your class path, but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I have also tried using the other mockito library `com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.mock`, that also kept telling me `final class cannot be mocked`.

I have also done multiple project rebuilds at multiple stages in these process, just in case.

Comment: are you writing your tests under `androidTest` or `test` ?

Comment: `androidTest`... I guess I should put the extension into that folder instead? Ill try it tomorrow.

Comment: @a_local_nobody yep, that fixed it. that was stupid of me. If you want to post an answer ill gladly accept it.

Comment: glad it helped, when i saw `androidTestImplementation` it seemed a bit odd that your extension was under `test`, although i normally just have my tests under `test`, i don't write many instrumentation tests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `androidTestImplementation` be sure to add the relevant files and extensions to the `androidTest` folder instead of just normal `test`